# CompileError: WebAssembly.compile()

Tags: google-chrome, webassembly

I am trying to execute basic C code of calculating factorial in WebAssembly and when I am loading WASM file in Google Chrome ( 57.0.2987.98) I am getting

> CompileError: WebAssembly.compile():
>   Wasm decoding failedResult = expected magic word 00 61 73 6d,
>   found 30 30 36 31 @+0`

C Code :

```
double fact(int i) {
  long long n = 1;
  for (;i > 0; i--) {
    n *= i;
  }
  return (double)n;
}
```

WAST :

```
(module
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (export "_Z4facti" (func $_Z4facti))
  (func $_Z4facti (param $0 i32) (result f64)
    (local $1 i64)
    (local $2 i64)
    (block $label$0
      (br_if $label$0
        (i32.lt_s
          (get_local $0)
          (i32.const 1)
        )
      )
      (set_local $1
        (i64.add
          (i64.extend_s/i32
            (get_local $0)
          )
          (i64.const 1)
        )
      )
      (set_local $2
        (i64.const 1)
      )
      (loop $label$1
        (set_local $2
          (i64.mul
            (get_local $2)
            (tee_local $1
              (i64.add
                (get_local $1)
                (i64.const -1)
              )
            )
          )
        )
        (br_if $label$1
          (i64.gt_s
            (get_local $1)
            (i64.const 1)
          )
        )
      )
      (return
        (f64.convert_s/i64
          (get_local $2)
        )
      )
    )
    (f64.const 1)
  )
)
```

WASM Compiled Code :

```
0061 736d 0100 0000 0186 8080 8000 0160
017f 017c 0382 8080 8000 0100 0484 8080
8000 0170 0000 0583 8080 8000 0100 0106
8180 8080 0000 0795 8080 8000 0206 6d65
6d6f 7279 0200 085f 5a34 6661 6374 6900
000a c380 8080 0001 bd80 8080 0001 027e
0240 2000 4101 480d 0020 00ac 4201 7c21
0142 0121 0203 4020 0220 0142 7f7c 2201
7e21 0220 0142 0155 0d00 0b20 02b9 0f0b
4400 0000 0000 00f0 3f0b 
`
```

Code executed in Chrome :

```
 async function load(){
        let binary = await fetch('https://flinkhub.com/t.wasm');
        let bytes = await binary.arrayBuffer();
        console.log(bytes);

        let module = await WebAssembly.compile(bytes);
        let instance = await WebAssembly.Instance(module);
    }
    load().then(instance => console.log(instance.exports.fact(3)));
```

Can anyone help me out, I have been stuck on this for a whole day and not able to understand what is going wrong.
I used [WebAssembly Explorer](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/) to to get the WAST and WASM code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [WebAssembly Explorer](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/)'s download capability you reference, I get the following file (as seen with hexdump):

```
0000000 00 61 73 6d 01 00 00 00 01 86 80 80 80 00 01 60
0000010 01 7f 01 7c 03 82 80 80 80 00 01 00 04 84 80 80
0000020 80 00 01 70 00 00 05 83 80 80 80 00 01 00 01 06
0000030 81 80 80 80 00 00 07 95 80 80 80 00 02 06 6d 65
0000040 6d 6f 72 79 02 00 08 5f 5a 34 66 61 63 74 69 00
0000050 00 0a c3 80 80 80 00 01 bd 80 80 80 00 01 02 7e
0000060 02 40 20 00 41 01 48 0d 00 20 00 ac 42 01 7c 21
0000070 01 42 01 21 02 03 40 20 02 20 01 42 7f 7c 22 01
0000080 7e 21 02 20 01 42 01 55 0d 00 0b 20 02 b9 0f 0b
0000090 44 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 0b                  
000009a
```

That's a valid `.wasm` binary which starts with the magic `00 61 73 6d` a.k.a. `\0asm`. According to the error message you get, your file starts with `30 30 36 31` which isn't valid.

Double-check the `.wasm` file you have.

Decoding `30 30 36 31` as ASCII gives `0061` which seems to be your problem: you're loading the textual version of your hex file. Sure enough, the URL you provide (https://flinkhub.com/t.wasm) contains the following content as-is (I didn't hexdump it! It's ASCII):

```
0061 736d 0100 0000 0186 8080 8000 0160
017f 017c 0382 8080 8000 0100 0484 8080
8000 0170 0000 0583 8080 8000 0100 0106
8180 8080 0000 0795 8080 8000 0206 6d65
6d6f 7279 0200 085f 5a34 6661 6374 6900
000a c380 8080 0001 bd80 8080 0001 027e
0240 2000 4101 480d 0020 00ac 4201 7c21
0142 0121 0203 4020 0220 0142 7f7c 2201
7e21 0220 0142 0155 0d00 0b20 02b9 0f0b
4400 0000 0000 00f0 3f0b
```

I'm guessing you overwrote the file saved from the Explorer.

Comment: I understand the idea. But let's say I save the small text area in a code.wasm file and I do : `let wasm = await fetch('code.wasm');`. I will get the error. How do I save it in the right format ? When I do `file -I code.wasm`, I get `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`, I guess I should convert to `application/octet-stream; charset=binary`. How ? :)

Comment: @fabien see https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Web.md#webassemblycompilestreaming
The resolved `Response` is used as the source of the bytes to compile.
MIME type information is
`extracted`
from the `Response`, WebAssembly `source` data must have a MIME type of `application/wasm`,
extra parameters are not allowed (including empty `application/wasm;`).
A MIME type mismatch, a response whose
type is not "basic", "cors", or
"default", or a response whose status is not an
ok status, must cause the Promise to be
rejected with a
`TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting GOARCH and GOOS environment variable correctly in zsh shell of mac before generating wasm object. Looks like go compiler does not recognize both these variables unless you explosively export them as a global variable in the parent shell. I simply exported both variables and run the compiler.

```
% export GOARCH=wasm
% export GOOS=js
% go build -o hello.wasm hello.go
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your system, but I am using react and esbuild.wasm where while running the below code I was getting error.

```
const service = await esbuild.startService({
     worker: true,
     wasmURL: "/esbuild.wasm/esbuild.wasm"
 })
```

esbuild.wasm is in my public folder along with node_module.

So I corrected the url which is  `wasmURL: "https://unpkg.com/esbuild-wasm@0.8.27/esbuild.wasm"` and now it is working.

Comment: The documentation for running esbuild in the browser is here: https://esbuild.github.io/api/#running-in-the-browser. In version 0.9.0, esbuild.startService() became esbuild.initialize() and service.build() became esbuild.build() (i.e. the explicit service object disappeared). So updated code might look something like this:   ```const service = await esbuild.initialize({
     worker: true,
     wasmURL: "/esbuild.wasm/esbuild.wasm"
 })```

Answer (score 0):

`30 30 36 31` is the hex dump of the string `"0061"` which is the start of the hex dump of your wasm binary. Did you somehow fetch the textual hexdump instead of the actual binary?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this error means that instead of the binary .wasm file your browser received something else. That can be a error page generated by the web server or the same .wasm but corrupted somehow. I recommend to open your browser Developer Tools, go to Network tab, Refresh the page and look at the .wasm resource request and response.